# How to switch between two WiFi adapters in command line?

Tags: networking, 22.04, raspberrypi, netplan, wifi-hardware-switch

I managed to get my external wifi adapter (`MT7601u`) work in my raspberry pi 4 thanks to help from [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555).

Now I have two wifi interfaces, `wlan0` (raspberry pi's built-in wifi) and `wlx8c882b02d94e` (`MT7601u`)

the wlan0 is currently connected to my home wifi, but the other one is showing its essid as `off/any`.

[image: off/any]

How do I make the other wifi adapter connect to my WiFi through command line and how can I switch between the two? (e.g. disconnect `wlan0` from wifi and connect the `MT7601u` to wifi instead), preferably in such a way that it automatically does it as soon as I instruct it to switch from `wlan0` to external wifi adapter? Since I am running my pi headless (accessing through ssh), so I won't have access to the Pi if it will go offline which switching connection.

edit: output of `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

`This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following: network: {config: disabled}`

`network:`

```
ethernets:

    eth0:

        dhcp4: true

        optional: true

version: 2

wifis:

    wlan0:

        access-points:

            GenericSsid:

                password: xxxx

            GenericSsid2:

                password: xxxx

            GenericSsid3:

                password: xxxx

        dhcp4: true

        optional: true
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify that the wireless is being configured in netplan and, if so, add the 'netplan' tag.

Comment: I am not sure whether the wireless is being configured by netplan or not, i tried running these two commands and this was the result: `dpkg -l |grep wpasupplicant
ii  wpasupplicant                         2:2.10-6ubuntu2                         arm64        client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant-$(uname -r) | grep Status
dpkg-query: package 'wpasupplicant-5.15.0-1011-raspi' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.`

Comment: The correct command is: `sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant | grep Status` Where did you set the SSID and password for wlan0? Please edit your question to add the result of: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` If there are passwords shown, please redact them with XXXX.

Comment: result of ` sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant | grep Status
Status: install ok installed` But when I check `/etc/wpa_supplicant`, the wpa_supplicant file is not there `ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/wpa_supplicant$ ls
action_wpa.sh  functions.sh  ifupdown.sh`, also I accidentally typed `wpa_supplicant`,which outputted `ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/wpa_supplicant$ wpa_supplicant
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant v2.10
Copyright (c) 2003-2022, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under…… example:
  wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: But when I checked `/etc` there is no wpa_supplicant.conf file there

Comment: Stop, please! First, we have established that the needed package wpasupplicant *is* installed. That's all we needed. Second, please do not issue terminal commands tat you do not understand and that are not requested by us. You could damage your installation. Finally, as I requested, please edit your question to add the result of: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` If there are passwords shown, please redact them with XXXX.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience i caused, and sorry i couldn't add the result of yaml file yesterday as the stack exchange blocked me from editing the question yesterday

Comment: Is GenericSsid: correct? Is that what the file actually says or is it disguised? Frankly, I don't see how the wireless connected at all.

Comment: No that is disguised, in that place were the ssids of my home, phone and work network, I just replaced the name and passwords to “genericssid” (I didn’t changed the file, the yaml file still has ssid of my home network in place of “GenericSsid”)

Comment: I regret that I know of no way, other than editing and applying the netplan configuration, to easily switch between the internal wifi device and the USB wifi device. I recommend that you stick to whichever device works better and blacklist or remove the other.

Comment: will it work if i remove the `wlan0` (under "wifis:") from the netplan configuration and replaced it with `wlx8c882b02d94e`?

Comment: I strongly believe that it will work perfectly.